# How can I instantaneously add a cell to a tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Currently, I have a table view that the user can add items and delete items from. However, the adding feature currently works by pulling up a modal view, gathering the information from there, and adding it into an array from which my tableview is loaded from every time it loads. With this setup I have to reload the entire view whenever data is added.

What I want to do is add a cell, like in this video at about 0:12 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAebrhW3SHg

In this example, a new cell just pops right out when the add button is pushed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` when you get a button press, and use `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` to place the cell without any animation. You won't need to reload your table.

Comment: Just an observation: in the linked video the row animation seems to be UITableViewRowAnimationTop

Comment: You're right about the animation. OP said "instantaneous" so I went with that instead.